# on:click doesn't work when the DOM is updated in Svelte

Tags: svelte

The `send_random()` doesn't work when I added it as a directive in the newly added DOM.

```js
        ...
            for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                data = `
                    <div class = "block received">
                        <span class = "item-text">
                            <button type = "submit" on:click = ${send_random}>
                                ${items[i]['text']}
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                `;  
         ...
```

Your help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add Svelte code like that.

It has to be added as part of the template (i.e. not in the script) to be compiled properly.

In general you should not manipulate DOM like that. Add data to lists/set local state and then use `{#if}`/`{#each}` to build the DOM.

Comment: Thank you, but I could add Svelte code in that way. In this example, the DOM is added, but the event is not applied. I think the way I assigned the function is what caused the issue.

Comment: No, you really can't. It is not "Svelte code" unless it is compiled, and that code will not be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Reactively creating the variables solved my problem, you can try it too.

```
let variable = "..."
```

changed to

```
$: variable = *some queries or logics*
```